# windows phone 8 camera events

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, background, camera

I am developing an App which needs to capture an event when the user takes a photo. But I don't want to use the photo task within my app, I mean, this app runs in background and when the user decides to use the camera and takes a photo, then the app shows a toast and uses the Stream to save the photo to the local storage.

I would like to know if doing this is possible and, if so, how could I do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, you want when an user want to take photo, the phone use your app instead of the normal photo task?

Comment: Not at all. What I want is when a user takes a photo, then catch this event without using the camera from the app. The app what does is just catch the event when the photo is taken and then performing some actions. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't but when your application is use for update picture or other things about picture, your application can be found in --> Photo --> application (item of pivot)